# eclipse layout of a window

Tags: eclipse, editor

I am using to debug applications.
When debugging, I find that the values of variables in a window are displayed at the bottom, as shown in the figure -

[image]

However, when I display the expression, I get the layout like this -

[image]

My Question is that, is it possible to change the layout of variables window also to display the values at the right, since it is convenient for me.

Thank You !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the arrow at the top right corner (the one pointing down). Then select `Layout -> Horizontal`